# prometheus-promql query based on label value

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm new to promethues. Is there a way to query timeseries based on label value i.e if it is greater or lesser than a label value ?

eg: assume a gauge metric is {mountpoint='/test',usage='90%'} with value 1

how to write promql query to get results with label 'usage' > 80% irrespective of gauge value?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would be better off making that gauge metric a histogram and using [histogram_quantile()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile) instead

See [Prometheus histograms](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) and step 3 of this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-query-prometheus-on-ubuntu-14-04-part-2) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion :) . I will explore the options.
 Is there a way to write query asked in the question ? i just want to know out of curiosity :)

Comment: I don't think so!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't recommended to put frequently changed values into labels, because this may result in [high cardinality issues](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-cardinality). Ideally all the labels must be static. So the `usage` label must be put into time series value instead. E.g. the resulting metric should look like `usage{mountpoint="test"} 90` when expressed in [Prometheus text exposition format](https://github.com/Showmax/prometheus-docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md#text-format-details). In this case the PromQL query, which returns disk space usage greater than 80%, will look as simple as `usage > 80`.